# How to convert YY to YYYY ORACLE

Tags: oracle, date, plsql

How to convert YY to YYYY, example below, if I run example below I will receive for year '0007':

```
   DECLARE
       lv_promcode_txt VARCHAR(6) := 'A0807X';
       lv_prommth_txt VARCHAR2(7);
       lv_promyear_txt VARCHAR2(7);
   BEGIN
       lv_prommth_txt := SUBSTR(lv_promcode_txt, 2,2);
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Month of promo code is: '|| 
       TO_(TO_DATE(lv_prommth_TXT,'MM'), 'MONTH'));

       lv_promyear_txt := SUBSTR(lv_promcode_txt, 4,2);
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Year of promo code is: '||TO_CHAR(TO_DATE  
       (lv_promyear_txt, 'YYYY'),'YYYY'));
   END;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your format mask is wrong.  Example:

```
   select TO_CHAR(TO_DATE (SUBSTR('A0807X', 4,2), 'YY'),'YYYY') from dual
```

returns 2007

Answer (score 3):

Replace your last `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` part of the code with

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Year of promo code is ( Style 1 ) : '||TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(lv_promyear_txt, 'YYYY'),'YYYY'));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Year of promo code is ( Style 2 ) : '||TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(lv_promyear_txt, 'RRRR'),'YYYY'));
```

Just changing `YYYY` literal `RRRR` is enough in `TO_DATE` function.

This concept is related to `year 2k problem`.

For a date `TO_DATE('18', 'RRRR')` gives the result `2018` as year ( for
 *the current century*, and `the last two digits of years` are between `00`-`49` ),

*while*

For a date `TO_DATE('74', 'RRRR')` gives the result `1974` as year ( for
 *the previous century*, and `the last two digits of years` are between `50`-`99` )

Comment: I have another question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48132856/i-need-for-price-code-to-be-asked-only-if-type-e, please Barbaros could you check it out?