# I need for price code to be asked only if type := E

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have small problem here, I want portion of the code lv_price_num := '&lv_price_num'; to be initiated if TYPE := 'E', however when I run the code it will prompt to enter the price regardless of the type, rest is working fine.

```
    DECLARE
      lv_type_txt CHAR(1);
      lv_price_num NUMBER(4,2);
      lv_disc_num NUMBER(3,2);
    BEGIN 
      lv_type_txt := '&lv_type_txt';
      IF lv_type_txt = 'E' THEN
         lv_price_num := '&lv_price_num';
            IF    lv_price_num > 85 THEN
                  lv_disc_num := .20;
            ELSIF lv_price_num > 45 THEN
                  lv_disc_num := .15;
            ELSE  lv_disc_num := .10;
            END IF;
        ELSIF lv_type_txt = 'C' THEN
              lv_disc_num := .05;
        ELSE lv_disc_num := 0;
        END IF;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(lv_disc_num);
   END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whenever you call a variable with an ampersand, related statement perceives it as a parameter. You may call it as a procedure or function to suppress such a response :

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_PROC( lv_price_num NUMBER, lv_type_txt VARCHAR2 ) IS
      lv_disc_num NUMBER(3,2);
    BEGIN 
      IF lv_type_txt = 'E' THEN
            IF    lv_price_num > 85 THEN
                  lv_disc_num := .20;
            ELSIF lv_price_num > 45 THEN
                  lv_disc_num := .15;
            ELSE  lv_disc_num := .10;
            END IF;
        ELSIF lv_type_txt = 'C' THEN
              lv_disc_num := .05;
        ELSE lv_disc_num := 0;
        END IF;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(lv_disc_num);
   END;
```